# Is it possible to re-create a "onClick event" using custom events in javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, custom-events

I'm trying to learn about [custom events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) and I got curious.  Could you create the onClick event verbatim but written in a Custom Event?

**ex.** create an element:

```
<h1 id="clicky">click here</h1>
```

Create a custom event that is the same as click event?

```
obj = document.getElementById('clicky');

obj.addEventListener("fakeClick", function(e) { console.log(e.detail) });


var event = new CustomEvent("fakeClick", {
  detail: {
    hazcheeseburger: true
  }
});

obj.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Heres a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matty0187/g15pnnv7/)

Comment: As the error states, the function `process` defined in your handler is not defined. (`obj.addEventListener("fakeClick", function(e) { **process**(e.detail) });`)

Comment: replace `process(e.detail)` with `console.log(e.detail)` and have fun

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan so I've replaced with console.log() and yay no more error.  Problem is the #clicky element isnt clickable?

Comment: @MatthewHarwood sure it's not clickable. You just created a custom event, not a clickable event. Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on what you mean by making it 'the same as click event'.
Custom event fire to the corresponding Dom element when you call dispatchEvent (like what u did above). So basically if u **dispatch** the custom event **within a click event handler**, then it basically simulate a click event, but there seems not much reason for doing so.

p.s. The error u got from fiddle is because u haven't defined the function `process` that u called in the `fakeClick` event handler

========== more details =========

What I meant was you can use custom event in the following way to 'simulate' click event, but that really doesn't serve the purpose since you can just directly use the browser click event.

```
var event = new CustomEvent("fakeClick", {
  detail: {
    hazcheeseburger: true
  }
});

obj = document.getElementById('clicky');

obj.addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.dispatchEvent(event);
});

obj.addEventListener("fakeClick", function(e) { console.log(e.detail) });
```

Comment: How would I use a "click event handler."  I'm prob never gonna do this just curious if possible.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood have you read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events ? It's all there.

Comment: Just got linked Reading it now... I see that there are MouseEvent. I'll test it out.

Comment: added more details to my answer @MatthewHarwood